# "Originating Lead" field is empty after lead is qualified

Tags: mapping, entity, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, lead

The problem is that when I try to qualify a lead in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Online the "Originating Lead" field for newly created Opportunity is left empty. This is strange because all the mappings are there and it should be transfered.

Does anyone have any ideas about this or have encountered something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originating Lead display name is the Name of the Lead. If the Lead's Name is empty, the Originating Lead will be empty, although there is a relationship between 2 records.

I assume you have made First Name and Last Name of Lead optional. If so, you should write a JavaScript or a plugin to update those fields before qualifying a Lead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't help much. There is a mapping for when lead is qualified. And LeadId from Lead is mapped to OriginatingLeadId from Opportunity. There is actually no such fields as First and Last Name as far as I understand.

Comment: Please have a look at fields table of Lead entity, there are `firstname` and `lastname`. `fullname` is made up from these `firstname` and `lastname`. OriginatingLeadId is an `EntityReference` which has two attributes: `Id` and `Name`. As default behavior when a Lead is qualified, the Id of the Lead is mapped to `OriginatingLeadId.Id` and `fullname` is mapped to `OriginatingLeadId.Name`. So in your case, you must have missed the `Name`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been looking into it for a very long time and couldn't find a solution, even contacted the MS support. Not sure how I didn't try this before. Anyway, thanks once again, everything worked!